# Using Powershell rename files with serial number based on order of Last modified

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I now have 2600 images in a folder I want to rename with a serial number starter from 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and so on. I want to start with the oldest files first and rename them as mentioned.

One file can be qwe01.jpg Last modified 01.05.2012
next file can be ewe202.jpg Last modified 05.05.2012
and so on...

I want these to be renamed in the correct order based on the date modified.

Answer (score 0):

This is not completely tested, but it should work:

```
$count = 1; Get-ChildItem -file | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | %{$newName = '{0}{1:00}.{2}' -f $_.basename, $count, $_.extension; Rename-Item $_ -NewName $newName; $count++}
```

Comment: Does not work. Gives the error: Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.

Comment: Then I suspect that you are on a version prior to v3